# Ver equipos de red vpn por nombres

Tags: vpn

Tengo conectadas dos red por medio de una conexión vpn "red A" y "red B", la cual funciona correctamente, pero solo puedo ver los equipos desde la "red A" a la "red B" por medio de la dirección ip del equipo \ip_de_host\carpetas_compartidas, como hago para verla por medio de el nombre del equipo \hostname\carpetas_compartidas.

Comment: Teóricamente deberías poder utilizarlo por nombres, hasta los mapeos de unidades tienen que funcionar. Cómo configuras la VPN?

Comment: Probablemente te hará falta un servidor DNS o WINS

Comment: tengo configurado un WNS 2012 con el acceso vpn configurado, posee un dns, segun lo que he leído para que los desktop's windows resuelvan los nombres de netbios de la red el server debe tener esta opción habilitada, lo tengo de esa manera pero aun sigue sin funcionar, me puedes ayudar?

Comment: Si el servicio wins y dns funciona , los clientes deberían usarlo. O sea, que en la configuracion de tcp/ip de los que se conecten a la VPN ponga que usen su servidor WINS y DNS.